# equals giving false even though state of object is same in java

Tags: java

My code looks somewhat like this :

```
public class EqualityTrial {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EqualityTrail1 obj1 = new EqualityTrail1();
    obj1.setName("Ankit");
    obj1.setAge(23);
    EqualityTrail1 obj2 = new EqualityTrail1();
    obj2.setName("Ankit");
    obj2.setAge(23);

    if(obj1 == obj2){
        System.out.println("== gave true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("== gave false");
    }
    if(obj1.equals(obj2)){
        System.out.println("equals gave true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("equals gave false");
    }

  }

}
```

every time both the conditions is giving false.
I know == compares if reference is pointing to same object which in this case is not so false is a correct result but in case of 'equals' method as far as i know it compares state of both the objects...If the state is same method should return true which in this case is returning false even though state of both the objects is same. AM i missing something here ?

Comment: For your EqualityTrail1 class implement equals method and then compare. See here how to do it : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/

Comment: It does not compare the _state_ of the object.

Answer (score 5):

`equals` compares state only if you override it in your `EqualityTrail1` class with an implementation that compares state. If you don't override it, the default implementation (from Object class) is used, and that implementation compares the references (so it will behave exactly the same as `==`).

A possible implementation:

```
public class EqualityTrail1 
{
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
         if (!(other instanceof EqualityTrail1))
             return false;
         EqualityTrail1 oet = (EqualityTrail1) other;
         return this.name.equals(oet.name) && this.age == oet.age;
    }

}
```

Comment: In case i am not overriding what is it going to comapre?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the equals to work property, you will have to implement an own variant of equals(Object obj).

There you can specify how the 'measuring' of equalness should be applied to the object.

Some example (used Eclipse, Source tab):

```js
public class MyClass {

  String sequence;

  public MyClass(String seq) {
    this.sequence = seq;
  }

  @
  Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((sequence == null) ? 0 : sequence.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    if (sequence == null) {
      if (other.sequence != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!sequence.equals(other.sequence))
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you rewritten the method `equals` of class `EqualityTrail1` ? If not this is the problem. If yes post your `equals` method

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide an implementation for `equals`, which should compare each field in turn, Java will use the default version in `java.lang.Object` which, according to the JLS:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

So, since you have two distinct objects, they will *not* compare equal by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had not overwritten the equals method....after doing the same it worked thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: I realized that i had provided implementation of equals method in my class ...After doing that i am getting correct answer that i was expecting